# How to set the property ;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE to oracle db url?

Tags: java, spring, jndi

How to set the property `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE` with oracle connection URL?

The solution I have tried:

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522/xe;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE`

But it's not working.

I am using Java, Spring, JNDI and oracle dataSource.

I have addShutdownHook that runs before the spring context destroyed, my requirement is to save the in-memory cached data in the database before application shutdown. The addShutdownHook is working fine but when it triggers the JNDI connections already closed and no more database connection is available and it throws below error:

Sql Failed to execute: SHUTDOWN because Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-173]

This is how we set this with H2 database:
`jdbc:h2:<url>;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE`

Before this code executes, JDNI connection already closed and it throws the above exception.

````
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        log.info("Application shutting down, saving the API Event Log data to the database...")
        apiEventLogCacheService.saveAPIEventLogCacheToDB();
    }
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use this URL:

```
jdbc:h2:<url>;MODE=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

Comment: This ```jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522/xe```  is the oracle URL I have in my configuration. Where to set? I have tried settingit like this: ```jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522/xe;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE``` but it's not working.

Comment: `DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT` is an H2 feature, not and Oracle.

Comment: Why do I get this error when I am not using H2 database:

```Sql Failed to execute: SHUTDOWN because Database is already closed (to disable automatic closing at VM shutdown, add ";DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE" to the db URL) [90121-173]```